# Simple Form and Bootstrap errors hidden when outside input?

Tags: bootstrap-4, simple-form

I have form errors not associated with an input field (confirmation_token), but the error is hidden.

```
= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: confirmation_path(resource_name), html: { method: :post, class: 'dark lg' }) do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = f.full_error :confirmation_token
```

[image]

[image]

This is because in bootstrap the css for .invalid-feedback is hidden unless wrapped in one of these:

```
.was-validated .form-control:invalid ~ .invalid-feedback, 
.was-validated .form-control:invalid ~ .invalid-tooltip, 
.form-control.is-invalid ~ .invalid-feedback, 
.form-control.is-invalid ~ .invalid-tooltip {
    display: block;
}
```

Simple Form is supposed to integrate here, but unfortunately this is a fail. It's using the right Bootstrap class, but the wrapper doesn't come with it. I can make a work-around. But shouldn't this work?